# About coding this binary tree in Python

Tags: python, binary-tree

I have a question about coding up a binary tree, and I'm currently stuck on it.

Basically, the algorithm is as follows where at the initial node, we have the following objects: 1,2,3 placed in order as `(None,2,3)` with object 3 > object 2 > object 1. In each stage of the tree, one object can move to their immediate right or left and be placed with another object if that object that is moving is smaller than the object that is placed at the current position. If the position to the immediate right or left has a `None` position, then only the smallest number may move over from the right or left position. For example, it is possible to have the events of `(None,0,2+3)` and `(None,1+2,3)` after the initial node.

Hence, the tree is as follows: [image]

I am wondering how to code this up in Python. I dont really care about the replicating events so at each point, I am only interested in the unique tuples/events that occurs.

Im not sure but a rough idea I have is to do this:

```
def recursion():
    pos = list(range(1,4))
    index = 0
    values = list(range(1,4))
    tree = []
    if pos[index+1] > pos[index]:
        pos[index + 1] -=  pos[index+1]
        pos[index + 2] += pos[index+1]
        tree.append(pos)
    if pos[index+1] < pos[index]:
        pos[index+1] += pos[index]
        pos[index] -= pos[index]
        tree.append(pos)
    else:
        recursion()
    return tree
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain the movement rules better. What exactly is "the current position"--the position where the object is moving to? How can `(1,0,2+3)` become `(1,2,3)`? The two moved left but it is not smaller than the item at that position (`0`)? There are other questionable moves.

Comment: (1) How does this process end?  This looks to me like a directed graph with loops, not a binary tree.  (2) Your use of `0` appears incorrect; should this be `None`?  In one case, you moved `1` to `0`, which violates your "smaller" movement rule.  (3) With the rules you've given, this is not a binary tree; some configurations permit more than 2 moves.

Comment: What results do you get from your given code?  What do you expect from this format?  I don't see how your tree structure works: there's no node object -- none of the structures available for manipulating trees.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I edited the post, and i initially left out the case of 0, where the smallest number may move over if it is a 0. I have changed 0 to `None` so that it would be more clear

Comment: @Prune I followed your advice about changing it to `None` so that it is excluded from the "smaller" movement rule. What I hope to obtain is just to be able to see the total possible combination of events for any arbitrary stage. I'm flexible with any structure but for me it was more intuitive to use a binary tree. Could you explain how to use a directed graph ?

Comment: @PutsandCalls, I can't explain for two reasons: (1) I'm still not entirely clear on your state transition rules, and (2) an introduction to graphs and state machines is well beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Actually, I do understand directed graphs and what you said does make sense. I could define an adjacency matrix since I know that the total number of possible states is 9. But likewise, I'm not quite sure how to specify the transition probabilities either, and so i think it may be easier to use a binary tree. Can I ask what you are unclear about for the state transitions rules ?